# What is the difference between hasaccepted and isaccepted?

Tags: support, search

The [Advanced Search Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=) give the options *hasaccepted* and *isaccepted*. I can't really understand the difference between them.

Please explain it to me. If possible, give me some question links, so that I can understand this better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/search):

- `hasaccepted`:  **questions** that have an accepted answer (or not)
- `isaccepted`: **answers** that are accepted answers (or not)

One is for questions, the other for answers.

---

It doesn't change a lot if you use them alone. However, if used with another operator, like for example `user:me`, you have different results:

Own questions with an accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+isaccepted:1
Own answers which have been accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me+hasaccepted:1

Comment: @Gnoupi If a question has got answers and one of the answer is accepted, what difference does it make in searching with either `hasaccepted` or `isaccepted`.  Still I couldn't understand and differentiate from searching point of view.  Can you explain me this with an example?

Comment: @Gnoupi  So these 2 search options makes sense only when combined with another operator but not alone.  Am I correct?  By the way, is there any link on this topic in http://blog.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @Gnaman: well, you get the same Qn page, but it makes a difference to what you first see on that page.

Comment: @Charles Any relevant link for this topic in http://blog.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @Gnaman: Not that I know of.